# How to solve this non linear differntiatial equation solvable for p

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

The question is $$(x^2+x)p^2 +(x^2+x-2xy-y)p+y^2-xy=0$$ I have tried everything possible to solve it but I could not arrive at the solution. This is where I am stuck.
$$(x^2+x)p^2+((x-y)^2+(x-y))p-y^2p+y^2-xy=0$$
$$\implies (x^2-x)p^2+(x-y)(x-y+1)p-y(yp+y-x)=0$$
After that what to write I don't understand and also not sure whether this process is correct.
And $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Do you mean $p=y'$? Right?

Comment: Yes Exactly ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$(x^2+x)p^2 +(x^2+x-2xy-y)p+y^2-xy$$
$$=p^2x^2+px^2-pxy+p^2x+px-py-pxy-xy+y^2$$
$$=px(px+x-y)+p(px+x-y)-y(px+x-y)$$
$$=(px+p-y)((px+x-y)$$

Can you take it from here?